# Azurite throwing Exit due to unhandled error

Tags: .net, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-emulator, azurite

Today my laptop ran out of battery and after turning it on again I tried to run Azurite and I got the error on the image below. I tried a few things so far with no luck.

Did anyone come across this issue before?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like Azurite metadata is corrupted (potentially due to the unexpected power lost). You can try to remove existing metadata files under following path and try again.

[image]

Comment: work for me. I got a blue screen and after that the Azurite will not work, so I did remove the .json files and 2 folders and works fine... just lost the data :(  it was temp data so not a big deal, but it's worrisome.

Comment: This worked for me, however I have azurite disabled in VS and run it from the command line because I have multiple projects hitting it. So bare in mind if you do this the _xxx_.json files are located in the directory that powershell/cmd is currently running in e.g. /users/xxxx/ not the azurite.exe directory

Comment: Had the same problem after a blue screen. Running Azurite from VS, but the directory above was empty. Instead I found the metadata files in (userdir)\AppData\Local\.vstools\azurite. Deleting them there solved my problem.